# how to have a list selector and a text input side by side

Tags: r, shiny

Im trying to have a dropdown list selector and a text input side by side. im using a `splitLayout` approach but the result looks inconvenient and uncomfortable to use

```
column(3,
       titlePanel("Paso 1: Carga de archivos base"),
       #Month selection
       splitLayout(cellWidths = c("50%", "50%"), 
       selectInput("mes", "Seleccione el mes:",
                   c("Enero"        = "01",
                     "Febrero"      = "02",
                     "Marzo"        = "03",
                     "Abril"        = "04",
                     "Mayo"         = "05",
                     "Junio"        = "06",
                     "Julio"        = "07",
                     "Agosto"       = "08",
                     "Septiembre"   = "09",
                     "Octubre"      = "10",
                     "Noviembre"    = "11",
                     "Diciembre"    = "12"
                     ), width=120) ,            
        textInput( "year", "Ingrese el año:", value="(YYYY)",width=120)),
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to use it specifly for dates or do you need a generic widget?

Comment: So far, my requirement is only for month and year. i could accomodate though

Answer (score 1):

The `airDatepickerInput` in `shinyWidgets` let's you pick dates just by month and year.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- basicPage(
 airDatepickerInput("date",
                    "Choose Date",
                    value =  Sys.Date(),
                    minDate = "1900-01",
                    maxDate = "2025-12",
                    view = "months", 
                    minView = "months", 
                    dateFormat = "MM yyyy",
                    language = "es"
   ),
  
  textOutput("date_year")
)


server = function(input, output, session){
  
  output$date_year <- renderText({
    format(as.POSIXct.Date(input$date), "%Y%m")
    })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: will look into it as an alternative. whats does the calendar button do? i click on it and nothing happens.

Comment: also, i have been working with this date format `yyyymm = paste(input$year,input$mes, sep="")` based on my initial input text. how can i preserve it with your recommended widget?

Comment: The documentary says: "This icon act likes an actionButton, you can retrieve value server-side with input$<inputId>_button." If you don't like it, you can add `addon = "none"` in the `airDatepickerInput` function.

Comment: `yyyymm <- format(as.POSIXct.Date(input$date), "%Y%m")`

Comment: im making some progress but a strange thing is happening though. when i select january 2021, yyyymm=202012 / february 2021, yyyymm=202101 / march 2021, yyyymm=202103

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. When I select january 2021 i get 202101 and for february 2021 I get 202102.

Comment: :( im clueless. ive been trying to isolate the issue but cant seem to find where is the month being altered. can it be related to the locale ?